# unity snap object on another object

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im new to unity and I need to snap object to another object as its children.

I have hull, the hull has mounting point and turret. If i press... Num7, for example, the hull will change, and the mounting object changes as well, but i need the turret to lock on the new hull. And if i press Num4, the turret changes and it needs to stay locked on the mount as well.

Basically i need to remake this app, but now i need to know how to snap objects.. by their name or something.
https://youtu.be/6Kf-O6eJ4p8?t=634

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. show us what you tried and whats the code that not wroking

Comment: If you make your turret a child of the mount object, the turret will "stay in place"

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: Philipp, i havent yet made it. I need to know what my aim is before i can do so. I this case, how to make it. only then i begin it.
Dave, yes, but as i stated before, the models will change and when model changes, it would be nice if the turret would get adjusted to the new location.
Hugo, the problem is that i dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When making a tank prefab, first create the Empty Object that will hold the rest of the objects. It'll be the parent object for the rest. Then add parts' objects.

When you remove the hull you just replace it with another hull, and since the turret is not the child of the hull object it will not be affected and will move as it was moving before.

Edit 1: Clarification: Each object is a separate tank (I'll just call it tank if you don't mind). Because your question didn't mention modifications at first I will update my answer accordingly. Each tank will hold 1 hull, 1 turret and 4 turret mods in a hierarchy.

So, what you should do is:

1. Make Empty Object in a scene, call it Tank;
2. Add Script as component, call it Tank;
3. This script will be subclassing MonoBehaviour;
4. Add Hull, Turret, Mods properties in the script, those are Game Object properties except for Mods, which is List of Game Objects.
5. Add a Hull Game Object (that I assume you already have) to the Tank Game Object. Make sure it's positioned correctly. Add Turret GO as Hull's child and Modification GOs as Turret's children.
6. Each Hull, Turret and Modification should have scripts attached to them.
7. Hull script should have snappingPosition property of Position type. Turret should have a List of Positions named snappingPositions.
8. After the objects are positioned properly note their Transform components. Values of each object's Transform Position are important for you, because if each Hull has different height or alignment the snapping point will have different position. What you want to do is to save that snapping point for each Hull Game Object inside Hull script. So go ahead and save Turret's position as a Snapping point in Hull and Mods' positions in snappingPoints of Turret.
9. Replace Turret with another one at the same position as current Hull's snapping point and align modification properly. Save Modifications' position as snapping points for this Turret.
10. Repeat 9 until done for all Turrets.
11. Replace Hull object and align turret properly. Save Turret's position as Hull's snappingPosition. Repeat for all 3 hulls.

Now each time when you are switching hull/turret/modification when editing just replace the turret, transfer all modifications by using SetParent (of their Transform component?), adjusting their positions to snapping positions from Turret script, then adjust Turret's position to snapping position on Hull script and destroy the old turret.

Edit 2: I now understood that it's a hull that has modifications, not Turrets. Therefore Hull should have Mods positions saved as modsSnappingPoints property. And when you change the hull you move all mods to a new one, update positions, move turret, update position and then delete the old hull.

Comment: but if 1 object holds 7 hulls, each with 4 modifications, each modification containing about 30 objects (Each wheel,2 tracks, mounting point and hull itself)+11 turret types each with 4 modifications, wouldnt it make it resource heavy?
I mean, its player driving with 840 objects, excluding the turrets themselves. Each hulls modification having 44 turrets mounted on itself would literaly probably kill my laptop. (36 960 objects in total, if each hull has all turrets mounted on them)

Comment: @DageLV, sorry if I misunderstood you. One object is one tank. I will amend my answer.